# how to run another app from my app with a specified height(for example half screen)-B4A

Tags: android-intent, basic4android

In B4A (Basic for android) I know how to run another application from my app. this could be done using "phone" library and using intent. now my question is that how can I start the another app from my app with a customized width or height (for example second app be shown in half screen). Or showing the second app in a panel, or dialog, or something like them. how can I do that? 
thanks

Answer (score -1):

That is impossible. You cannot embed other applications' UIs into your app.